# Convert Array to 2d Array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

How can I convert an Array `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ,8, 9, 10, 11, 12]` to a 2D-Array looking like this?

```
[[1,  2,  3],
 [4,  5,  6],
 [7,  8,  9],
 [10, 11, 12]]
```

Always 3 Numbers in a row.

What I have tried returns the first line correct, but the other lines are the same as the first.

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
    for (int k = 0; k < 3; ++k) {
    result[k][i] = args[i];
    }
```

Comment: Any efforts put in till now?

Comment: Hint: use two nested loops. That's not the only solution - [read this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19197231/335858) to find out more.

Comment: Sry I've edited the question.

Comment: Hint 2 : Think what will the values of i and j be on each iteration of the loop.

Comment: SO is not a suitable resource for learning programming basics. You would be better talking to your teacher or reading a book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shall work for you:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length/3; ++i) {
  for (int k = 0; k < 3; ++k) {
    result[i][k] = args[i*3+k];
  }
}
```

Here we are computing the source index array based on `i*3+k` to keep on getting the next index value.

Answer (score 0):

An one-line and debatably readable solution would be:

```
int[] foo = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ,8, 9, 10, 11, 12};
System.out.println(
    Arrays.deepToString(
        new int[][]
            {
                Arrays.copyOfRange(foo, 0, 3),
                Arrays.copyOfRange(foo, 3, 6),
                Arrays.copyOfRange(foo, 6, 9),
                Arrays.copyOfRange(foo, 9, 12)
            }
        )
);
```

**Output**

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
```

**Note**

Method `Arrays.copyOfRange` is only available from Java 6. 
Otherwise you have to use `System.arrayCopy` which returns `void` (not applicable to example as is).

Answer (score 0):

arr1 - array with input numbers

arr2 - array with output numbers

```
for(int i=0;i<arr1.length;i++)
for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
arr2[i][j]=arr1[i*3+j];
```